# Assign value to shared_credentials_file using environment variable in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, terraform

I want to use `%USERPROFILE%\\.aws\\credentials` to assign value to shared_credentials_file in terraform but I get the error

```
No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider
```

If I hardcode the path like "C:\Users\admin\.aws\credentials" this, it works fine.

How can I make it work with the environment variable?

Comment: Looks your credentials file has been set to default path, I will test with aws cli, such as `aws s3 ls`, if you can see any buckets in output, it proves the aws credentials works, otherwise, fix this issue firsts

Comment: I can get the list of buckets with the command aws s3 ls. I gave users/admin as an example. It is user/myname/.aws/credentials in my machine will be similar in other team member's machine. What I want is to use the environment variable %USERPROFILE% in the terraform so that everyone can use it without any change.

Answer (score 1):

You have some different options for making fields dynamic outlined [here](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html).

If you wanted to use an environment variable, you have to export it with `TF_VAR` prepended at the beginning and then you can you can use it without the `TF_VAR` in your code.

```
export TF_VAR_shared_credentials_file="/Users/admin/.custom_aws/credentials"
```

And then in your terraform .tf file:

```
variable "shared_credentials_file" { }

provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "${var.shared_credentials_file}"
}
```

Or you can pass in the environment variable as terraform variable when calling terraform commands like `plan` and `apply`.

```
terraform plan -var 'shared_credentials_file=/Users/admin/.custom_aws/credentials'
```

Also in the docs for AWS [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/), in the Shared Credentials section it states:

> You can use an AWS credentials file to specify your credentials. The
>   default location is $HOME/.aws/credentials on Linux and OS X, or
>   "%USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials" for Windows users. If we fail to
>   detect credentials inline, or in the environment, Terraform will check
>   this location.

So if you ensure that everyone keeps their .aws credentials in the default location, you don't need to worry about adding this interpolation yourself.

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the value in TF_VAR as that will be different for each team member using it and also for each env.  I can pass it as a variable but what I am interested in is to use the environment variable %USERPROFILE% in the terraform script so that everyone can use it without any change. Is this possible to do in terraform ?